# How to sort array of local data based on distance to current user in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, cllocation

I have a model and some data:

```
class Clinic {
  var name: String
  var lat: Double
  var long: Double

 init(name: String, lat: String, long: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.lat = lat
    self.long = long
 }
 static func fetchClinic() -> [Clinic] {
     var clinicBizs = [Clinic]()
     let clinic1 = Clinic(name: "ABC", lat: 12.000, long: 22.000)
     let clinic2 = Clinic(name: "XYZ", lat: 11.000, long: 25.000)
     let clinic3 = Clinic(name: "ZZZ", lat: 10.000, long: 26.000)
     clinicBizs.append(clinic1)
     clinicBizs.append(clinic2)
     clinicBizs.append(clinic3)
 }
}
```

In my VC I have:

```
var currentLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D!

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

let location = locations[locations.count - 1]
if location.horizontalAccuracy > 0 {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}

self.currentLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude) //Print shows current loc
```

}

How do I sort the clinics based on the distance to the current user?

I have tried this but it didn't work:

```
        //$0.locations <-I tried to give CLLocation to the model instead of lat and long
//Error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
let loc = self.clinics.sorted (by: { $0.locations(from: self. currentLocation!) < $1.locations(from: self. currentLocation!)} )
```

Answer (score 0):

you need change class Clinic

```
class Clinic {
    var name: String
    var location: CLLocation

    init(name: String, lat: Double, long: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.location = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
    }

    static func fetchClinic() -> [Clinic] {
        var clinicBizs = [Clinic]()
        let clinic1 = Clinic(name: "ABC", lat: 12.000, long: 22.000)
        let clinic2 = Clinic(name: "XYZ", lat: 11.000, long: 25.000)
        let clinic3 = Clinic(name: "ZZZ", lat: 10.000, long: 26.000)
        clinicBizs.append(clinic1)
        clinicBizs.append(clinic3)
        clinicBizs.append(clinic2)
        return clinicBizs
    }
}
```

and sort

```
  let current = CLLocation(latitude: currentLocation.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.longitude)
  let loc = self.clinics.sorted (by: { $0.location.distance(from: current) < $1.location.distance(from: current) })
```

Comment: Same error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Comment: sr. I fixed it but didn't see "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context "